# Powering 5V 1A Device From Battery

Tags: power, batteries

I have a small toy electromagnetic levitation device that I need to power externally instead of being plugged into a wall. The device uses an AC/DC adapter with a barrel jack connection that outputs 5V at 1A. What can I replace this with to power it without an outlet? I have an Anker USB battery pack. Will that work somehow with a certain cable? I don't know much about this topic. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut a usb cable and use the 5 volt wires, believe they are black and red. Just use a meter to find the 5 volts.

Comment: Crude but effective.